# Valid inequalities in a polyhedron

Tags: inequality, linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Let $\alpha, \beta >0, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\pi \in \mathbb{R}^n, \pi_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $P\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a polyhedron, such that the inequalities:
$$\pi x \leq \pi_0 +\alpha (x_j -k) $$
$$\pi x \leq \pi_0 +\beta (k+1-x_j)$$
are valid, for all $j$.
I am asked to prove that then, the inequality
$$\pi x \leq \pi_0$$
is valid in $P \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$.

I have tried many ways of combining the equations, so that I can get to the result, but so far, without much luck. I don't see a way of using the fact that the points are whole numbers, but I guess it has to do with the parameter k. I have also tried working in one or two dimensions, to see if there is any pattern in the inequations, but they don't seem to give a particular structure. I also tried to use the floor function, but the vector $\pi$ doesn't let me do anything.

Please help, I just need to know where to start from.

Comment: Exercise 8.11 in Wolsey, *Integer Programming* (1998)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- $x_j\in\mathbb{Z}$ implies the disjunction $(x_j \le k) \lor (x_j \ge k+1)$.
- Valid for $P \cap \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: x_j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ for all $j$ implies valid for $P \cap \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.